# Bind Razor Pages property using alias

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

`MyPage.cshtml.cs`

```cs
[BindProperty(Name="name")]                            // notice the alias
public string ProductName { get; set; } = "example";
```

`MyPage.cshtml`

```html
<input asp-for=@ProductName />
```

That renders:

```html
<input type="text" id="ProductName" name="ProductName" value="example">
```

But what I want is:

```html
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="example">
```

How can I make it render the alias instead?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. If you want to set the `id` and `name` attribute to something other than the public property's name, you need to revert to plain HTML as you have done.

Comment: @MikeBrind I suppose I could also write a custom tag helper. But that's no fun. Thanks for confirming the situation. It's a minor issue I'll just live with it.

Comment: `asp-for=xx` will generate `id="xx" name="xx"` by design, You can't change it, Or as you said you can custom tag helper